# tensor flowのバージョンアップを行った結果、checkpointファイルのフォーマットが変更されている

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflowの学習モデルの出力フォーマットが以前のものとは変更されており、
model.ckptだけであったのが
model.ckpt-1111.data-00000-of-000001,
model.ckpt-1111.index,
model.ckpt-1111.meta
といった具合に3ファイルに変更されており対処に困っています。

どのckptファイルを参照するのか、またコード例が知りたいです。
~~~下記は自分が使っているコードの一部です~~~

```
images_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(None, IMG_PIXELS))
keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
logits = inference(images_placeholder, keep_prob)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
```

Answer (score 1):

tensorflow r12よりcheckpointファイルのフォーマットが変更されております。

とりあえず過去フォーマットでsaveしたいのならば

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saver_pb2
...
saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version = saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)
saver.save(sess, './model.ckpt', global_step = step)
```

としてください。(cf:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048819/how-to-restore-a-model-by-filename-in-tensorflow-r12)

restoreに関しては

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

cf:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265035/tensorflow-why-there-are-3-files-after-saving-the-model